# Python - Pacman heuristic is not consistent

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, consistency, pacman

As part of a AI homework I have to solve the Pacman Project from UC Berkeley. You can find the (already solved) source code here under `search/searchAgents.py`: [source code](https://github.com/advaypakhale/Berkeley-AI-Pacman-Projects)

The problem I have is that in the `foodheuristic` a consistent heuristic for finding all food is required. I already found out that if I take the real distance in the maze from the pacman position to the most distant food, I have a sufficient heuristic. But my thought was that if I get the furthest distance between two food points and add the distance between pacman position and the nearest point of one of the two found points together I would have an even better solution.

Like: `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` have the most distance between them in the maze. That means that pacman has to travel at least this distance, no matter what. But in case pacman did not spawn directly onto one of the two points he also has to travel at least the distance between his current position and the nearest of the two points. But when I do this I get the alert that my heuristic is not admissible or even consistent. Which does not make sense to me.

My code also notes the possibility of 2 food point pairs having both the maximum distance by using a list for them. So the code can later on determine the lowest distance to the pacman position out of all pairs.

The code:

`mazeDistance(x,y,default)` finds the lowest real path in the maze between point x and y

```
position, foodGrid = state

foodList = foodGrid.asList()#is a list that contains all food positions
if not foodList:
    return 0
elif len(foodList) == 1:
    return mazeDistance(position, foodList[0], problem.startingGameState)
distancesBetweenFood = []
for foodNode in foodList:
    foodList2 = foodList
    foodList2.remove(foodNode)
    for foodNode2 in foodList2:
        distancesBetweenFood.append([mazeDistance(foodNode, foodNode2, problem.startingGameState), [foodNode, foodNode2]])
highestDistanceBetweenFood = max(distancesBetweenFood)[0]
highestDistanceNodes = []
for dist,nodes in distancesBetweenFood:
    if dist == highestDistanceBetweenFood:
        highestDistanceNodes.append(nodes)
lowestDistanceBetweenFoodAndPacman = 9999999#should be infinite
for nodes in highestDistanceNodes:
    manhattanDists = []
    manhattanDist = 0
    for n in nodes:
        manhattanDists.append(mazeDistance(position, n, problem.startingGameState))
    manhattanDist = min(manhattanDists)
    if manhattanDist < lowestDistanceBetweenFoodAndPacman:
        lowestDistanceBetweenFoodAndPacman = manhattanDist
sumDist = lowestDistanceBetweenFoodAndPacman + highestDistanceBetweenFood
return sumDist
```